# Gradle builds every subproject when a unit test is executed

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I have a project consists of multiple sub projects, which are defined in the settings.gradle file.

Whenever I run a unit test of one of the projects, it always "configures" and compiles dependent modules again even though there is no changes on them.

This is really painful since it takes a while to finish it. I didn't have this problem before on the same project, but it suddenly appeared. Any ideas how to fix it? 
I use intellij for IDE and gradle for build. The output looks like this:

```
> Configure project :xx1
compiling YYYY
> Configure project :xx2
compiling YYYY
> Configure project :xx3
compiling YYYY
> Configure project :xx4
compiling YYYY
```

Comment: Do you use `dependsOn clean` somewhere in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're probably aware, a task will only run if it's `UP-TO-DATE` check fails. A task's `UP-TO-DATE` check will

- Take a hash of the current task inputs
- Take a hash of the current task outputs
- Compare the current hashes against the hashes of the previous run of the task
- The task is considered `UP-TO-DATE` only if both current hashes match the previous hashes

Try running gradle passing the `-i` flag (or `--info`) to see the results of the `UP-TO-DATE` checking. I'm guessing a task has its inputs/outputs configured incorrectly causing an `UP-TO-DATE` check to fail somewhere in your task tree. Perhaps you are using the current date/time somewhere as a task input? (don't do this!). Maybe two tasks are copying files to the same directory? (don't do this)

A good way to verify your build is to:

1. Run a clean build
2. Run a build again without cleaning

In a perfect world, the second build won't do any work. If the second build executes any tasks then it's likely there's some task inputs/outputs which are incorrectly configured